# -nginx, uwsgi, 502 Bad gateway on domain

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I was looking all over the internet for solutions, but none helped. 
I want to deploy a django project at my server pointed to vps.florisdeboer.com. I've read some tutorials and did exactly what they told me, but the 502 error keep showing up.

I've got all important files, if you miss something, please comment while I can post it as an edit.

OK, let's go:

The projectname is webshop. Nothing special, just a webshop build in django. I use db.sqlite3 as my database.

/etc/uwsgi/sites

```
[uwsgi]    
project = webshop
uid = floris
base = /home/%(uid)

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/BIT/
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

plugins=python27
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name florisdeboer.com vps.florisdeboer.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/floris/webshop;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/website.sock;
    }
}
```

And the `sudo systemctl status uwsgi`

```
● uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-06-17 22:13:00 CEST; 17h ago
 Main PID: 24782 (uwsgi)
   Status: "The Emperor is governing 1 vassals"
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
           ├─24782 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
           ├─24785 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini webshop.ini
           ├─24788 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini webshop.ini
           ├─24789 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini webshop.ini
           ├─24790 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini webshop.ini
           ├─24791 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini webshop.ini
           └─24792 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini webshop.ini

Jun 18 15:54:21 srvrfloris systemd[1]: Started uWSGI Emperor service.
Jun 18 15:57:20 srvrfloris systemd[1]: Started uWSGI Emperor service.
Jun 18 15:58:18 srvrfloris systemd[1]: Started uWSGI Emperor service.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or una was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Here is the same command as above but for `nginx`

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-06-18 15:54:13 CEST; 14min ago
 Main PID: 882 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─882 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           └─883 nginx: worker process                           

Jun 18 15:54:13 srvrfloris systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a revering A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...

Jun 18 15:54:13 srvrfloris systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/n.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument

Jun 18 15:54:13 srvrfloris systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reversed A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

~
```

The error-log from `root $ uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/webshop.ini`

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/sites
*** WARNING: Can't find section "uwsgi" in INI configuration file /etc/uwsgi/sites ***
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Sun Jun 18 23:08:20 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 17 June 2017 21:30:14
os: Linux-4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017
nodename: srvrfloris
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/floris
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3826
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.
```

I hope someone can help me with this!

Cheers,

Floris

Comment: what are the permissions on %(base)/%(project)? and on "/run/uwsgi" dirs?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 2 floris www-data 40 Jun 18 16:16 /run/uwsgi` for /run/uwsgi

Comment: `drwxrwxr-x 7 floris floris 4096 Jun 17 21:27 /home/floris/webshop` for /home/floris/webshop

Comment: OK, for testing purpose I suggest that you run your uwsgi manualy in forground. it could be some error when trying to start uwsgi (ps: have you checked the access to the static files?)

Comment: OK, but how do i do that? I really have no clue

Comment: run on the command line: `uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites` (assuming it's the ini file and not the directory). better run it as root

Comment: Check out the edit ive made @Tamar

Comment: It seems that the uwsgi didn't parse the ini file. Maybe your version is deferent from mine. try to run it "uwsgi /etc/uwsgi/sites" w/o --ini, or copy all the directive to the command line (--uid, --socket etc).

Answer (score 1):

If the question is actual.
in that line change website to the webshop unix:/run/uwsgi/website.sock;
and reboot you droplet or server.